# Only scrape specific details from a web page

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup, html

I am using Jsoup to retrieve details from a webpage and write into a text file. Is it possible to for me to retrieve only parts of it? For example in the following link, I want to take only the job description.

http://aldogroup.luceosolutions.com/recruit/stores/advert_details.php?id=3136&_lang=en&partner_id=139

Sometimes the job postings are from different websites and therefore the format of the html tags may vary. I need a way to retrieve just the job description only. The following code retrieves everything on the web page. How can I get only the job description? Please help.

```
public class MainCollector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://aldogroup.luceosolutions.com/recruit/stores/advert_details.php?id=3136&_lang=en&partner_id=139").get();
            String title = doc.title();
            String body = doc.body().toString();
            Document convertText = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(body);
            String convertedText = convertText.text();
            System.out.println("Title:" + title);
            System.out.println("Body:" + convertedText);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this -

```
Elements e = doc.select(".annonce > p:nth-child(5)");
System.out.println(e.text());
```

To get the right `CSS selector` you can open your browser's developer tools (by pressing F12), and then choosing the inspector tool.
You should also add the `user agent` string to your request, so you will get the exect same page both from your browser and your program -

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://aldogroup.luceosolutions.com/recruit/stores/advert_details.php?id=3136&_lang=en&partner_id=139")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0")
                .get();
```

Comment: For this page : https://sjobs.brassring.com/TGWebHost/jobdetails.aspx?jobId=88557&PartnerId=25592&SiteId=5175&codes=INT-INDEED I want to get only the contents in the div tag "PrimaryContentBlock". How to specify this in the code?

Comment: Well, to get the content of that specific tag, you can use `Elements e = doc.select("#PrimaryContentBlock");`